# How to find $\langle \mathbf{J}\rangle$ in a quantum system with angular momentum $j = 1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum

I was trying to solve this following exercice:

> Consider a system of angular momentum j = 1, whose state space is spanned by the
> basis $|+1\rangle$, $|0\rangle$,$|-1\rangle$ of three eigenvectors common to $J^2$
> (eigenvalue $2\hbar^2$) and (respective eigenvalues $+\hbar$, 0 and $-\hbar$). The state of the system is:
>
> $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|+1\rangle + \beta|0\rangle + \gamma|-1\rangle$
>
> where $\alpha$,  $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are complex parameters.
>
> a) Calculate the mean value $\langle \mathbf{J}\rangle$ of the angular momentum in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.
>
> [...]

So, my problem is to understand what should $\langle \mathbf{J}\rangle$ mean ? Can I think of $\mathbf{J}$ as the direct sum of $J_x$,$J_y$, and $J_z$ ? If so, then I would have $\langle \mathbf{J}\rangle = (\langle J_x\rangle,\langle J_y\rangle,\langle J_z\rangle) = (\langle\psi|J_x|\psi\rangle, \langle\psi|J_y|\psi\rangle, \langle\psi|J_z|\psi\rangle)$ ?

Comment: It's just a standard sloppy notation. $\boldsymbol{J}$ is the vector $J_x,J_y,J_z$ as you said, not a direct sum.

Comment: Your guess is fine.

Answer (score 0):

J is the vector of Jx, Jy and Jz. Now using the rules of calculating the expectation values (see ladder operators), then the problem is solved.